# Wordress: hook/filter before get_previous_post_link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website in which `custom fields` are used to filter the content after the search of an "article".

After I click on an "article", the theme Astra adds "Previous article" and "Subsequent article" buttons with this code:

```php
$previous = get_previous_post_link(
        '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>',
        $args['prev_text'],
        $args['in_same_term'],
        $args['excluded_terms'],
        $args['taxonomy']
    );

$next = get_next_post_link(
    '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',
        $args['next_text'],
        $args['in_same_term'],
        $args['excluded_terms'],
        $args['taxonomy']
    );
```

But the filters of the `custom_fields` are not used.

For the normal search I use this function:

```php
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    $custom_fields = array(
        // put all the meta fields you want to search for here
        "nome",
        "nome_detto",
        "cognome",
        "cognome_detto",
        "nome_del_padre",
        "cognome_della_madre",
        "cognome_della_madre_detto",
        "nome_del_madre",
        "nome_del_madre_detto",
        "giorno",
        "mese",
        "anno",
    );
    $searchterm = $query->query_vars['s'];

    // we have to remove the "s" parameter from the query, because it will prevent the posts from being found
    $query->query_vars['s'] = "";

    if ($searchterm != "") {
        $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
        foreach($custom_fields as $cf) {
            array_push($meta_query, array(
                'key' => $cf,
                'value' => $searchterm,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }
        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
    };
}
add_filter( "pre_get_posts", "custom_search_query");
```

but it appears not working for the `get_previous_post_link`

Comment: If the queries performed by those two functions do apply the pre_get_posts hook as well - then this will probably be with their own, unique query instances, so `$searchterm = $query->query_vars['s'];` likely won't fetch any value. Try and use `$searchterm = $_GET['s'];` instead, to directly access the value that was passed via the URL parameters.

Comment: @CBroe How can I check if the function `get_previous_post_link` applies the pre_get_posts hook?

Comment: By following what it does in the source code, I guess, looking for do_action and apply_filters calls.